# What does "Blood was pounding in his ears" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Harry grabbed his broom.
>
> "No!" shouted Hermione Granger. "Madam Hooch told us not to move -- you'll get us all into trouble."
>
> Harry ignored her. **Blood was pounding in his ears**. ... ...

I understood its literal meaning(he can hear the beating of his blood), but I'm not sure if there is a figurative meaning for it. I searched it on the web, but I haven't found anything useful. How should we understand it correctly? Is it merely a literal meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Blood was pounding in his ears..." is a way of saying that someone's heart is beating faster and their blood pressure is high. It can be from anger, or fear, or excitement. One side effect is that it is hard to hear other people when your blood is pounding in your ears, so there is a sense of being overwhelmed by emotion. A similar expression is "[heart-pounding](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heart-pounding)."

Comment: Usually anger, but not necessarily.  In this context, it is most certainly anger.